# How can I use draw.io together with private gitlab with an access token?

Tags: draw.io

I have found [this thread](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/493) ([this comment sumarizes it](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/issues/493#issuecomment-545805060)) explaining how to use draw.io together with a private gitlab **by authorizing the application**. In my company that option is **not** available.I think it could be possible to give draw.io access to the private gitlab **by using access tokens** but I don't know how.

It is okey if it requires some changes to the source code, as anyways we will be building it and deploying it in a private server.

So far I tried to do basically the same process but changing the `gitlab-id` parameter from the `application-id` to the `access-token`, that didn't work. Any ideas? Thanks!